# Excel Concatenate Time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, concatenation

I have had a look at this site, and across the net, but can't seem to solve this, which should be easy! Concatenate should work, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Current spreadsheet looks like this:

```
B2: 8:00 (AM) (Start time)
C2: 1:00 () (Duration)
D2: 9:00 (AM) (End time)
```

I would like to have a formula in `A2` that looks like this: `8:00 - 9:00`, and obviously updates as soon as I make changes to the `B2` and `C2` (`D2` is already working with a formula)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is working in LibreOffice, but it seems, that the `TEXT` function and `&` operator is adapted from Excel:

> `=TEXT(B2,"hh:mm")&"-"&TEXT(D2,"hh:mm")`

Answer (score -1):

```
=TEXT(B2,"hh:mm AM/PM")&"-"&TEXT(D2,"hh:mm AM/PM")  
=8:00 AM - 9:00 AM
```

Comment: Can you please add some context/ explanationto your formula.