# Excel formatting: how to format time periods?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, text-formatting

I would like to format a time period like:

> 10:00 - 16:00

How do I?
And can I do it without dates?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/559641/387576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works for dates and/or times in cells **A1** and **A2**:

```
=text(A1,"HH:mm")&" - "&text(A2,"HH:mm")
```

[image]

To add the time period without the use of other cells you will need to type this manually into the cell:

```
="10:00 - 16:00"
```

Comment: Wow, OK. That's simple!

Comment: Wait, the two cells in A column, are they plain text, or are they formatted somehow?

Comment: I just typed "10:00" (without quotations) into cell A1. But you could type "22/01/2015 10:00" and get the same result. Excel recognises it as a time.